# TypeError: Cannot call method "insertChart" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to insert an embedded chart to a google sheet for data analytics.  However, when I run the code it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "insertChart" of undefined (line 87, file "Code").

This is my function for creating the chart:

```
function createBarGraph(activeSheet) {

var chart = activeSheet.insertChart()
chart.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
.setOption('Chart Title', 'Service reviews')
.setPosition(5,5,0,0)
.build();
}
```

`activeSheet` is a variable held in another function that creates a new sheet for each month.  The embedded chart needs to be created in that sheet to correctly reflect the data for each month.  I note I haven't added a `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet`, this is based on the assumption that since this is being called in the other function it is not needed here.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the code for the function calling this one.

```
function checkSheetName() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = formatDate(); // load the current 'Month-Year'
var activeSheet;

try {
activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
ss.setActiveSheet(activeSheet); // try to set 'sheetName' as active sheet
} catch (e) { // if returns error,
activeSheet = createNewMonthSheet(); // creates a new sheet 
} 
return activeSheet;
}

function createNewMonthSheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = formatDate(); // load the current 'Month-Year'
ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 2); // creates a new sheet on the left side, after 2   existing sheets
var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var columns = ['Comment','Compliment','Complaint']; // Array of review type.
var rows = ['Befriending','Finance','Fund Raising','Home Help','I & A','Mgmt 
Services','Toes Nails','Trading']; // Array of services provided.
          for(r=0; r<rows.length; r++){
          newSheet.getRange(r+2, 1).setValue(rows[r]);} // iterates through 
the length of row array, gets the range and sets the value.
for(c=0; c<columns.length; c++)
{
  newSheet.getRange(1, c+2).setValue(columns[c]); // iterates through length of column array, gets the range and sets the value.
}
  return ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); //returns active spreadsheet with date formated M & YYYY.
}

function formatDate() {
var monthNames = 
["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var monthNumber = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+12:00', "M");
var yearNumber = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+12:00', "yyyy");
return monthNames[monthNumber-1]+'-'+yearNumber;
```

}

Comment: Show the code for the other function that is calling this one.

Comment: Ross, thank you for your comment, I have added the additional code to my original question.

Comment: Sorry - I still can't see where you're calling `createBarGraph` inside the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart) for `insertChart()`, you have to call it after you build it, you're calling `insertChart()` before the chart is built.

Try writing the function like this:

```
function createBarGraph(activeSheet) {

var chart = chart.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
.setOption('Chart Title', 'Service reviews')
.setPosition(5,5,0,0)
.build();

activeSheet.insertChart()

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto, that works.  However, the chart doesn't appear in the sheet as expected. I suspect I am missing something, any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I forgot I had commented out my function call.  After calling the function it is still returning the same TypeError message.

Comment: @APStevens what does your function call for `createBarGraph` look like?

Comment: @ross I just noticed I hadn't declared the activeSheet as an argument of my createBarGraph() call.  I have now added this and removed the TypeError, however I now get Cannot find method insertChart(). (line 93, file "Code").

Comment: Now that its finding your sheet, I think @Alberto Molina's code should work for you.